# Windows 10, can't connect to some web sites

Tags: networking, dns

I have a windows 10 laptop that's experiencing intermittant network dropouts that affect connections to particular sets of web sites only.

Basically a web site will work for a while, then connection to it will show errors in the browsers such as "Taking too long". Whilst the affected sites are not working, other sites including sites I've never been to will continue to work. When the "timing out" web sites are down they are considered "down" on IE, Edge, Chrome, Firefox, Opera and I can't ping or tracert to them on the Windows 10 laptop. Other computers including Windows 10 and mac's on the same network with the same gateway are find and do not experience the problematic connections to the same sites at the same time.

I've tried:

- switching from wireless to a ethernet connection (both in combination with turning wifi off, and leaving it on)
- switching the ethernet from the internal to a usb3 ethernet dongle
- performing an `ipconfig /release` then `ipconfig /flushdns` then `ipconfig /renew`. This works for about 1 minute, then the affected sites go back to being inaccessible (time out)
- disabling the firewall
- disabling avant antivirus
- rebooting
- having two machines site by side (both windows 10, both same model asus laptop) and going to the same sites at the same time. one drops out, the other continues to work.
- making sure the hosts file is blank
- checking the time is correct on the machine (https works to various sites without complaining about the certificates)
- rebooted the router
- malwarebytes scan, etc

`ipconfig /renew` and flushing dns seems to resolve the issue for 1 minute or so, then it goes back to timing out, and it's only affecting a handful of sites .. can't figure out what it could be

Comment: When the problem happens, can you ping your own router, your DNS server, and other devices on your network?

Comment: It may be helpful to list sites affected. How long the error persists if you don't do `ipconfig /renew` ?

Comment: In addition to @Twisty, try to keep pinging your gateway, your dns server, and affected websites by adding `-t` to your ping command: `ping x.x.x.x -t`

Comment: Yes, the networking to other sites, including pinging them, works fine. I can load the routers web admin page from the same affected browser. pinging the router, for instance works just fine, as does pinging something like 8.8.8.8, whereas pinging the ip address of the affected sites does not, and doing a tracert to the ip of the sites just times out at every hop - very odd

Comment: How long the error persists if you don't do `ipconfig /renew` ?

Comment: afaik forever - as long as I've left it.

Comment: How about seeing if the problem persists from [Safe Mode with Networking](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10)?